# Стилизация reCaptcha. Возможно ли?

Tags: css, recaptcha

Есть WP. Вывожу формы с помощью Contact Form7. В форме есть капча от гугла. 
Каптча подгружается в iframe и берёт стили удалённо. Из-за этого я не могу на неё влиять через свой css.

Подскажите, есть ли способы стилизации капчи?

Comment: Если это капча, которая в виде "чекбокса", можно использовать тёмную тему, задав атрибут `data-theme=dark`.

Answer (score 1):

> Каптча подгружается в iframe 
>   . . . Подскажите, есть ли способы
>   стилизации капчи?

Нет никаких способов её стилизации. Содержимое `iframe` с чужого домена недоступно для взаимодействия. Политика безопасности браузеров.

Максимум, можно изменить внешние параметры контейнера (ширина, высота). Не более.